# Can I control one web app from another?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I'm developing a web application, in which there are some scheduled tasks (quartz-triggered).

Now I want to create a nice web front-end, which would allow me to start or stop those tasks.

If I implement this as two separate web applications inside Tomcat (2 WARs, one for the Quartz tasks, another - for the GUI), will the front-end part be able to control the back-end part (stop and start Quartz-triggered tasks) ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation  is it helpfull??

Comment: @LukášRutar I'm looking for an analogon of RMI for communication between web apps inside single Tomcat container.

Comment: @LukášRutar Can JMX be the answer? I. e. I provide MBean interfaces for my scheduled tasks and the web app accesses its state and operations via JMX.

Comment: sorry i don't know about JMX.

Comment: You can use RMI, Hessian, CXF or Axis for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the frontend is able to do whatever you want it to do. For example, the frontend may request some resource (of another application) via HTTP, you perform backend action you want - start quartz task.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for the web app to know whether a certain task is running? Or - can web app A access the servlet context of web app B?

Comment: If you mean quartz job, I think you have to implement this way-to-check yourself by publishing this information via some resource or web page (if this is for human :). I don't think you will be able to access `ServletContext` of another application. Even if I am wrong and technically you can do that, I would highly unrecommend that because of security and encapsulation issues.

Comment: What do you think about using JMX for communication between web app and the web app running the scheduled tasks?

Comment: AFAIK JMX is usually used to manage applications which includes monitoring, maybe profiling, some maintenance activities such as shutdown/restart. I'm not really sure whether this technology is suitable for some business logic related tasks, such as starting quartz job (which is I guess you intended).